# Domain keeps going back and forth between old and new hosting service

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, web-hosting, nameserver

I moved my domain yesterday from Heroku to DigitalOcean. The process went fine and the website seemed to be working fine on DigitalOcean. Today morning I noticed this error when I tried to access my website

```
Heroku | No such app 
There is no app configured at that hostname. 
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

I checked my domain registrar's (GoDaddy) settings and the nameservers had somehow gotten set back to the default settings. I changed them again to point to DigitalOcean nameservers. After about half an hour I was able to access my website again. But since then the domain at random times keeps on showing the same Heroku error and then after a few minutes starts working again. What could be causing such a bizarre issue? I've cleared my browser cache and cookies.

According to [this](http://intodns.com/edmhunters.com) the DNS seems to have propagated correctly.

The website is hosted using a DigitalOcean droplet on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All DNS records I can find for `edmhunters.com` are indicating it is hosted on `ns{1,2,3}.digitalocean.com` and those have `A` records pointing to `107.170.189.169`.

Since the DNS records look correct, it may be a caching issue. The `NS` records from the `TLD` servers have a 48 hour TTL. So if has been less than 48 hours, since you updated the records, you may just have to wait.

You can check the caches on the DNS resolvers provided by your own ISP. It is likely one of them has an old record cached, and the rest have the new record.